# Sonarqube 7 unable to start due to elastic search binary not found

Tags: sonarqube7

I have setup sonarqube 7, problem is i am getting below error while starting it -

```
2018.03.27 08:02:15 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.SQProcess] Fail to launch process [es]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find elasticsearch binary
        at org.sonar.application.command.CommandFactoryImpl.createEsInstallation(CommandFactoryImpl.java:111)
        at org.sonar.application.command.CommandFactoryImpl.createEsCommandForUnix(CommandFactoryImpl.java:80)
        at org.sonar.application.command.CommandFactoryImpl.createEsCommand(CommandFactoryImpl.java:76)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl$$Lambda$12/1128486197.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.lambda$tryToStartProcess$2(SchedulerImpl.java:153)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl$$Lambda$13/1288526896.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess.start(SQProcess.java:68)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStart(SchedulerImpl.java:160)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStartProcess(SchedulerImpl.java:152)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStartEs(SchedulerImpl.java:110)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStartAll(SchedulerImpl.java:102)
        at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.schedule(SchedulerImpl.java:98)
        at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:64)
```

Don't know why its unable to find elasticsearch binary file, as its already located inside its installation directory.

Anywhere i have to mention its path inside any config file of sonarqube 7?
This is a new installation & i am not finding any solution anywhere around. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error at my Gentoo Linux system. All 6.7.x versions didn't work with identical error (Cannot find elasticsearch binary).

I downloaded a fresh zip file from the sonarqube website (https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). The zipfile contains a elasticsearch subdirectory, but this folder was missing in my original installation (installed by Gentoo emerge using the Godin overlay: https://data.gpo.zugaina.org/godin/dev-util/sonarqube-bin/).

By copying the elasticsearch folder into my original installation my problem was solved.

I found this pull request fixing the ebuild for sonarqube-bin:
https://github.com/Godin/gentoo-overlay/commit/d52d7491e10d3589832bf4785edb29caf9dd4012

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i made it work by creating a softlink to elasticsearch folder inside the installation of sonra7. From sonar7 onwards i guess the installation is coupled with elasticsearch but this has to be located inside conf. files.